# How do I set 410 for entire website?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-410

We have a number of websites that have now been closed down and deleted however are still indexed in Google, even though they are returning a 404.

I want to set http 410 for everything on the domain, how would I do this in the htaccess? Use wildcards?

Answer (score 4):

> `I want to set http 410 for everything on the domain`

You can use this rule as your **first rule** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=410]
```

Don't forget to replace `domain.com` with your actual domain name.